# Random NaN placement in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to introduce random NaN in an existing dataframe. However, none of the following works.

```
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.binomial(size=df.shape, n=1, p=prob))
df[df_rand == 1] = float('nan')      # solution 1 (no effect on df)
df.where(df_rand == 1, float('nan')) # solution 2 (all entry NaN)
df.mask(df_rand == 1)                # solution 3 (all entry NaN)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is `prob` and does `df_rand` actually have any values equal to 1?

Comment: prob is in (0, 1). My test case is prob = 0.5. df_rand is a large dataframe. Inspection shows quite a number of 1 inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to make sure the index and columns same

```
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.binomial(size=df.shape, n=1, p=prob), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Second we need assign it back

```
df=df.mask(df_rand == 1)
```

Comment: Interesting. Without matching the index, all entries will turn to NaN.
Is it generally tru for df.mask if the argument is from another dataframe?